# multiplying an integer numpy array with a float scalar without intermediary float array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm dealing with very large image arrays of **`uint16`** data that I would like to downscale and convert to `uint8`.

My initial way of doing this caused a **`MemoryError`** because of an intermediary **`float64`** array:

```
img = numpy.ones((29632, 60810, 3), dtype=numpy.uint16) 

if img.dtype == numpy.uint16:
    multiplier = numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint8).max / numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint16).max
    img = (img * multiplier).astype(numpy.uint8, order="C")
```

I then tried to do the multiplication in place, the following way:

```
if img.dtype == numpy.uint16:
    multiplier = numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint8).max / numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint16).max
    img *= multiplier
    img = img.astype(numpy.uint8, order="C")
```

But I run into the following error:

> `TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc multiply output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint16') with casting rule 'same_kind'`

Do you know of a way to perform this operation while minimizing the memory footprint?

Where can I change the casting rule mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Numba or Cython in such cases

There you could explicitly avoid any temporary arrays. The code is a bit longer, but very easy to understand and faster.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def conv_numba(img):
    multiplier = np.iinfo(np.uint8).max / np.iinfo(np.uint16).max
    img_out=np.empty(img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            for k in range(img.shape[2]):
                img_out[i,j,k]=img[i,j,k]*multiplier
    return img_out

#img_in have to be contigous, otherwise reshape will fail
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def conv_numba_opt(img_in):
    multiplier = np.iinfo(np.uint8).max / np.iinfo(np.uint16).max
    shape=img_in.shape

    img=img_in.reshape(-1)
    img_out=np.empty(img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        img_out[i]=img[i]*multiplier
    return img_out.reshape(shape)

def conv_numpy(img):
    np.multiply(img, multiplier, out=img, casting="unsafe")
    img = img.astype(np.uint8, order="C")
    return img
```

**Timings**

```
img = np.ones((29630, 6081, 3), dtype=np.uint16)

%timeit res_1=conv_numpy(img)
#990 ms ± 2.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit res_2=conv_numba(img)
#with parallel=True
#122 ms ± 17.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#with parallel=False
#571 ms ± 2.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! I just had to write a second numba function with only 2 levels of loops to handle also grayscale (2D) image arrays.

I'm wondering if numba can also provide a solution for any number of dimensions, i.e. without the explicit loops?

Comment: @PiRK Yes, but there is a bit more information needed. eg. you can flatten the array (reshape(-1)) and than reshape it once again at the end. But there are only contigous arrays supported. If you do the reshaping outside of the numba function, flattening a strided array will lead to a copy, which you want to avoid. So for a full solution you will likely need two codepaths (one for a strided array, one for a contigous array)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will  have to keep the loops for now, until I find a low level library to read in the data in the right order. I'm reading in CZI files with a library that returns all the data with weird shapes (2, 3, 29632, 60810, 1) (axes "SCYX0"), and I have to perform some transposition to end up with my RGB images. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *"Do you know of a way to perform this operation while minimizing the memory footprint?"*

First, let's get the `[SPACE]`-domain sizing right. The base-array is 29k6 x 60k8 x RGB x 2B in-memory object:

```
>>> 29632 * 60810 * 3 * 2 / 1E9         ~ 10.81 [GB]
```

having eaten some **`11 [GB]`** of RAM.

Any operation will need some space. Having a **`TB`**-class `[SPACE]`-Domain for purely in-memory numpy-vectorised tricks, we are done here.

Given the O/P **task was to minimise** *the memory footpint*, moving all the arrays and their operations into **`numpy.memmap()`**-objects will solve it.

Comment: I will keep this answer in mind if I encounter even larger images that won't fit on my 16 Gb of RAM. :)

Comment: There is an improved **solution, having about a 4.3 ~ 4.8 x faster in-place processing** benchmarked and posted below

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution that works after some reading of the numpy ufunc documentation.

```
    multiplier = numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint8).max / numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint16).max
    numpy.multiply(img, multiplier, out=img, casting="unsafe")
    img = img.astype(numpy.uint8, order="C")
```

I should have found this earlier, but it's not an easy read if you are not familiar with some of the technical vocabulary.

Comment: This is my favourite solution, because I don't mind the performance hit, and it works in all cases (many different array shapes). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using integer division (instead of multiplying by the inverse) should prevent the intermediary floating point array (correct me if wrong) and allow you to do the operation in place.

```
divisor = numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint16).max // numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint8).max
img //= divisor
img = img.astype(numpy.uint8, order="C")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I get a similar error.
`TypeError: ufunc 'floor_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'H') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''`

Answer (score 0):

### **How about getting a `4.3 ~ 4.7 x` faster solution ?**

Polishing a bit the [*PiRK*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4494781/pirk)'s `numpy.ufunc`-based inplace processing solution, sketched [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998658/3666197),
there is **about a `4.3 ~ 4.7 x` faster** modification thereof:

```
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch() # a trivial [us]-resolution clock
>>> ###
>>> ############################################### ORIGINAL ufunc()-code:
>>> ###
>>> ###   np.ones( ( 29632, 608, 3 ), dtype = np.uint16 ) ## SIZE >> CPU CACHE SIZE
>>> I   = np.ones( ( 29632, 608, 3 ), dtype = np.uint16 )
>>> #mg = np.ones( ( 29632, 608, 3 ), dtype = np.uint16 ); aClk.start(); _ = np.multiply( img, fMUL, out = img, casting = 'unsafe' ); img = img.astype( np.uint8, order = 'C' );aClk.stop() ########## a one-liner for fast re-testing on CLI console
>>> img = I.copy();aClk.start();_= np.multiply( img,
...                                             fMUL,
...                                             out     =  img,
...                                             casting = 'unsafe'
...                                             ); img  =  img.astype( np.uint8,
...                                                                    order = 'C'
...                                                                    );aClk.stop()

312802 [us]
320087 [us]
329401 [us]
317346 [us]
```

Using some more of the documented **`ufunc`**-smart kwargs right in the first shot,
 the performance grows **`~ 4.3 ~ 4.7 x`**

```
>>> ### = I.copy(); aClk.start(); _ = np.multiply( img, fMUL, out = img, casting = 'unsafe', dtype = np.uint8, order = 'C'  ); aClk.stop() ########## a one-liner for fast re-testing on CLI console
>>> img = I.copy(); aClk.start(); _ = np.multiply( img,
...                                                fMUL,
...                                                out     =  img,
...                                                casting = 'unsafe',
...                                                dtype   =  np.uint8,
...                                                order   = 'C'
...                                                ); aClk.stop()
69812 [us]
71335 [us]
73112 [us]
70171 [us]
```

---

> **Q** : *Where can I change the casting rule mentioned in the error message?*

The implicit (default) mode, used for the `casting` argument, has changed IIRC somewhere between the `numpy`-versions 1.10 ~ 1.11, yet it is quite well documented in the published `numpy.ufunc` API documentation.

Comment: This does not work. The array type is not changed. Looks like the `dtype` argument is ignored when the `out` argument is provided. It makes sense that you can't change the output array's type in-place. A copy is unavoidable, for this step.

Comment: @PiRK Mea Culpa - I did test via .flags only the "F" to "C" ordering was POSACK'ed to get converted in-place, not the dtype.

Comment: I confirm this doesn't work. Try `img=np.uint16((0, 500, 65535))` as input. After calling the original solution, we get `array([  0,   1, 255], dtype=uint8)`. After calling your new solution, we get `array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)`.

Answer (score 0):

These are  alternative solutions that work in the specific case of converting `uint16` to `uint8`, suggested on https://github.com/silx-kit/silx/pull/2889, using the fact that you can just read the first byte and ignore the second one:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> img = numpy.ones((29632, 30000, 3), dtype=numpy.uint16)

>>> %timeit img2 = numpy.ascontiguousarray(img.astype(dtype=('u2', [('lo','u1'), ('hi', 'u1')])))["hi"]
2.43 s ± 34.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit img2 = numpy.ascontiguousarray(img.view(numpy.uint8)[..., 1::2])
2.58 s ± 165 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Combined with numba and parallel computation, it is slightly faster than the previous numba solution that uses an arithmetic multiplication (which took 750 ms on the same array):

```
In [11]: @numba.njit(parallel=True)
...: def uint16_to_uint8_shift(img):
...:     img_out = numpy.empty(img.shape, dtype=numpy.uint8)
...:     for i in numba.prange(img.shape[0]):
...:         for j in range(img.shape[1]):
...:             for k in range(img.shape[2]):
...:                 img_out[i, j, k] = img[i, j, k] >> 8
...:     return img_out
...:
In [12]: %timeit img2 = uint16_to_uint8_shift(img)
650 ms ± 43.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```